# Remove divider in Android Autocomplete View

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, android-view

I have a custom autocomplete view in android that shows contacts name and phone number. I have an image set as the background for each list item. All is working perfectly except I do not want the divider line to show between each contact.

I've seen some other posts on removing the divider from a list view ie using

```
android:divider="@null"
```

and/or

```
android:popupBackground="@null"
```

in the xml, but it doesn't seem to be working in the autocomplete view. Is there a way to remove the divider programmatically or through the xml?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you mean?